# Qt: Fonts not rendering for characters with accents and east asian languages

Tags: qt

I am adding the names of the langauges into a listview.

```
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("English");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("Deutsch");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("Español");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("Français");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("Italiano");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("日本語");
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem("한국어");
```

however, I am getting gibberish at runtime on anything with a special character (all asian, N of espanol, C of francais, etc) and it takes 5 seconds for the screen to render, when those characters are involved.

My listview font is Lucida Grande, 12. Should I use a different font? isn't QT supposed to be handling this for me?

**I am on Mac OS X**.

Comment: You'll probably want to use escape sequences for the characters in UTF-8 or whatever Qt supports. Even if the source files are encoded properly, that doesn't mean the compiler creates correct literals.

Comment: EScape characters, ok. I can see that happening for the Espanol's "N", but what do I do with asian languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using QString::fromUtf8 did the trick...

```
ui->CurrentLanguageList->addItem(QString::fromUtf8("한국어"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings.